# How do I set buffer limit for gtk_text_view in C?

Tags: c, gtk

I want my GtkTextView to display only a certain number of characters at the end of a long string. Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Comment: I've looked in the GTK documentation for GtkTextBuffer I cannot find any reference to buffer size or limits on buffer size. Why are you thinking about this?

Comment: Because in my application the GtkTextView will be filled with more and more text information,I doubt it'll crash if there is no limit.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the `insert-text` signal of `GtkTextBuffer`. In your callback, get the length of the text. If it's longer than the limit, get two start iters, and move one of them forward by the amount of characters you want to delete:

```
GtkTextIter range_start, range_end;
gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &range_start);
range_end = range_start;
gtk_text_iter_forward_chars(&range_end, num_chars);
gtk_text_buffer_delete(buffer, &range_start, &range_end);
```

That said, you'd have to put a *LOT* of text in a `GtkTextBuffer` to crash the application.

Comment: If you're dealing with several gigabytes, why are you even using a text view? No user is ever going to scroll through gigabytes of text. No user will even live long enough to do that! Maybe you need to filter the data or write it directly to a disk file.