# Set max number of characters in GtkTextBuffer

Tags: text, gtk, buffer

Is there a way to set the maximum number of characters for GtkTextBuffer? What I need is when the maximum number of characters is reached, further typing produces no output. Beep would be nice but not required. Or maybe I need to do something with GtkTextView?

I need my GtkTextView to serve as a word-wrapping single line entry, so I want to disallow Return characters as well.

I'm looking for a solution for GTK+2 and GTK+3.

Comment: @oldtechaa, I need a multilingual control.

Comment: @oldtechaa, sorry I meant to say multi-line. AFAIK, GtkEntry is single-line only.

Comment: @oldtechaa, word wrap. And the size of the control should be couple of 'virtual' lines long.. In fact pressing Enter should have no effect. So I'm looking for a multi-line text control which behaves as single line. If I can say that. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791035/how-do-i-set-buffer-limit-for-gtk-text-view-in-c) has a similar intent, but in this case, the poster wants to only display a certain number of tailing characters. ptomato (who would know more about it than I) recommends using a callback for typing to cut or truncate the string.

Your callback would be very similar, except that you would cut off the tailing characters and strip any newline characters as they were fed in.

You could also use a similar mechanism to the comment fields on SO, where you are notified that your string is too long and either disallow continuing or truncate it to size only when the data is actually being used.

For wrapping, you also want to read about [wrapping modes](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-set-wrap-mode), although you may already know about that.